# CS0103 The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

While I create android app in Visual Studio with Xamarin I got strange error - CS0103   The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context. When I do Clean and then Build, there are no any problems, build is success. But when I changes something in code, Error appears again. 
I tried to make changes according this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5261/the-name-resource-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) but all file names in Resources folder are ok. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Please post your complete error message.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT it's in title - CS0103 The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see more information to help you pinpoint the problem. You can add a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) to this, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possibly this known bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60343

Comment: @jimmyjudas Nope that's another bug

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT No. But as I noticed, it is not a build problem. Now I get this problem when I change source code in Android project files.

Answer (score 1):

**short:**

make sure your  Namespace is same across all these files that is mentioned below ;

- Resource.Designer.cs
- every *Activity* that procudes error:"cs103 resource doesnt exist .."
- yourproject.csproj  (edit vith notepad)(verify "RootNamespace" ,"AssemblyName" is same with your namespace  )

after you make them all same Namespace  clean+build  should work

---

**long:**

if you have changed namespace in anywhere in the project,

you gotta Find And Replace oldNameSpace to NewNameSpace inside yourProjectName.csproj file
(open with text editor outside of vs2015 ide)

**why ??**

when you compile project  **namespace in the Resource.Designer.cs  is overwritten** with this values from  *csproj* file

**Any Activity:**

```
namespace yourNew_NameSpace  //  <-- Attention here !!!!!!
{
    [Activity(Label = "asdf", MainLauncher = true )]
    public class act_main : Activity  
    {
        TextView tv_camResolution;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ly_main);

            tv_camResolution = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        }
        ......
```

**.csproj file :**

```
.... 
<RootNamespace>OldNameSpace</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>OldNameSpace</AssemblyName>
....
```

**Resource.Designer.cs:**

```
                                                          //▼▼▼below see oldnamespace 
[assembly:global::Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute("OldNameSpace.Resource", IsApplication=true)]


namespace OldNameSpace    // <--- and here see oldnamespace  
{

    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, but my code compile. so its maybe related to the wrong import or ambiguous Resources object. Note that there is Resources and Resource i believe Resources is coming from android sdk.